# multiline text to hash to YAML conversion produces last line

Tags: ruby, hash, yaml

1) I am trying to read strings from data.txt

```
Christopher Plummer;Dec 13, 1927
Christopher Walken;Mar 31, 1943
The King of Spain;Jan  5, 1938
```

2) split all strings at ';' and convert them to hash

3) hash to YAML

4) write YAML to file

**problem:** writing YAML to file produces only the last line

---

```
data = Hash.new
require 'yaml'
filename = 'Ydata.txt'

File.read('Data.txt').each_line do |line|
  line = line.chomp 
  line = line.split ';' 
  data = { "#{line[0]}" => "#{line[1]}" }.to_yaml  
end 

File.open filename, 'w' do |f|
   f.write data
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: you are replacing `data` every loop iteration, you have to either concatenate or put it in a array

Comment: you can save the file in one line: `File.write(filename, data)`

Answer (score 0):

This line is setting `data` to be the last value converted to yaml.  So it's completely replaced every loop.

```
data = { "#{line[0]}" => "#{line[1]}" }.to_yaml
```

Better would be...

```
data = {}
File.read('Data.txt').each_line do |line|
  line = line.chomp 
  line = line.split ';' 
  data[line[0]] = line[1]  
end 

File.open filename, 'w' do |f|
   f.write data.to_yaml
end
```

Alternatively, if you want to write out each item individually to the `filename` file, you can open the output file and do the `File.read` in a loop within the output file block...

```
File.open filename, 'w' do |f|
  File.read('Data.txt').each_line do |line|
    line = line.chomp 
    line = line.split ';' 
    data = { "#{line[0]}" => "#{line[1]}" }.to_yaml  
    f.write data.to_yml
  end 
end
```

Comment: I see. You made one large hash in place of a few one-line hashes. Also, I tried to keep the File.open in the loop hoping that it will write line by line to File as it did to terminal, but it did not.

Comment: ok, edited to show how you can output every line individually to the output file.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are overriding `data` in every iteration with a new YAML string with only one entry. This is why you see only the last line. Try building the complete ruby hash and converting the whole hash to YAML at the end. Like this:

```
require 'yaml'

data = Hash.new
File.read('Data.txt').each_line do |line|
  k, v = line.chomp.split(';', 2)
  data[k] = v
end
File.open('Ydata.txt', 'w') do |f|
   f.write(data.to_yaml)
end
```

Comment: You mean `data.to_yaml`?

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš Right. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know you can make it more compact. As I learn, I try hard to keep up the mental model of a solution from collapse all the time, and loose and longer script helps. But short , as it may be impenetrable at first, does look nice.